# Doxygen: Exclude undocumented files

Tags: doxygen

I have a framework which I am extending. There are some source folders which contain quite a lot of files and I want to document my work (especially those files which come from me) using doxygen.

Any file I am documenting contians a header:

```c
/**
 * @file my_file.c
 * @author Stefan F.
 * @date 28.05.2014
 *
 * @brief This file is awesome!
 */
```

Can I somehow tell doxygen to NOT include files without such a header?

I have already set

```
EXTRACT_ALL            = NO
```

Files which don't have a doxygen header are not generated but they are still listed in the file list.

Does anyone know how to configure doxygen to get that behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not aware of any part of Doxygen that will do *exactly* what you are looking for, however, the simplest way to achieve your aim is simply to only list the files you want doxygenning in the doxyfile `INPUT` line.

`INPUT = my_file_1.cpp myfile2.cpp moreofmyfiles/etc.cpp`

(Beware it's a *space* separated list.)

Depending on your folder structure you may need to set `RECURSIVE = NO`

If it's your own personal project and you can name your file myname_file.cpp you could use `FILE_PATTERNS` to select only those files beginning "myname_* - but I'm expecting that's not a viable set of circumstances.